# Electric charge is distributed over the disk $x^2 + y^2 \leq 5$...Find the total charge on the disk.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Electric charge is distributed over the disk 
>   $x^2 + y^2 \leq 5$ so that the charge density at $(x,y$) is $\sigma(x,y) = 2 + x^2 + y^2$ coulombs per square meter. Find the total charge on the disk.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^5(2+r^2)\space r\space dr\space d\theta=\frac{725\pi}2$$

is not the right answer.  I don't know why. Any help?

[image]

Comment: I am being marked wrong when I input my answer online.

Comment: The radius is $\sqrt{5}$, not $5$. You have the wrong limit of integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radius of the disk is $\sqrt{5}$, not $5$.  Change your upper integration limit and you'll get the right answer.  (The formula is $x^2+y^2=r^2$, not $\dots = r$.)

Comment: $=\frac{45\pi}2$...Thanks